# Kentico Claims-based authentication SAML 2.0

Tags: asp.net, saml, saml-2.0, claims-based-identity, kentico

I'm doing some research for the company I work for trying to determine if we're able to utilize Claims-based authentication within our clients application. According to [this](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/managing-users/user-registration-and-authentication/claims-based-authentication) web-page Kentico offers out of the box built in support for SAML 1.0 but version 2.0 isn't supported. Our client wants to use version 2.0 because it is the latest standard which seems like a reasonable desire. [This](https://docs.kentico.com/k9/custom-development/handling-global-events/handling-custom-claims-based-authentication) web-page mentions that Kentico is able to implement custom Claims-based authentication but I'm not sure how to go about doing that, or if it's worth the effort. It seems that if it were an easy task Kentico would have switch to version 2.0 by now. Does anyone know if there is an "easy" way to utilize SAML 2.0 within Kentico? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends a little on your definition of "easy", but there is no automatic nor out-of-the-box way to integrate SAML 2.0 with Kentico currently (especially if you want to do more than just authentication and actually use the info in the claim for something like role based authorization).

However, with that being said, we have accomplished SAML 2.0 integration with Kentico many times (both authentication and authorization) through custom code at my company, so it is possible. But it requires you to write custom code to do pretty much everything.

Also, let me add that with Kentico MVC the story is getting a little better. Check out this link on [external authentication](https://docs.kentico.com/k11/developing-websites/developing-sites-using-asp-net-mvc/developing-mvc-applications/working-with-users-on-mvc-sites/external-authentication-on-mvc-sites). But again, you are writing a lot of the code.

Comment: Unfortunately we are using Kentico via webforms so I don't believe we have ASP.NET Identity. I'm currently in the process of trying out a library. https://github.com/Sustainsys/Saml2/